# How to iterate through keys of object where keys are type `${number}` instead of string?

Tags: typescript

Say there is an object like:

```js
type Thing = {
  [prop: `${number}`]: string
}
```

When iterating through the object keys, the key is of type `string` rather than type `${number}`

```js
for(const prop in thing){
  //prop is a "string" here instead of `${number}`
}
```

I could probably just cast it, but it seems like code smell.

What is the best way to have prop be of type `${number}` instead of `string`?

Comment: What do you mean by _of type `${number}`_? Backticks are indicating a template literal, though `\`${number}\`` is of type `string`.

Comment: The type `\`${number}\`` is a *pattern template literal type* as implemented in [ms/TS#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598), and corresponds to any string which can be parsed as a number (even though [I argued it should require that the string be a possible *serialized* number](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41893#issuecomment-886099688)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amusingly enough, this "works" in that `props` will be typed as `${number}` inside the loop:

```
let prop : keyof Thing
for(prop in t){
    
}
```

However, as stated by @MatthieuRiegler, it actually just looks right (if you can get past how ugly it is), it does not provide the safety you'd think it does (there is [an open bug report about this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49882)).

Ultimately, it comes down to how `for..in` is typed. There is a long-standing discussion about this in [TS git](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3500).

I'm gonna go ahead and claim your best option for now is the cast you are reluctant about:

```
for(const prop in t){
    t[prop as keyof typeof t] = ''
}
```

unless you want to go down the type guard route:

```
function isThingKey(s: string) : s is keyof Thing {
  return !isNaN(Number(s))
}

for(const prop in t){
    if (!isThingKey(prop)) continue
    t[prop] = ''
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this happens is simple : there is no way to ensure your key will be of type  `${number}`.

Example :

```
type Thing = {
  [prop: `${number}`]: string
}

const foo= {
    "3": "ok",
    "x": "ko"
}

let thing: Thing = foo;

for(const key in thing) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

If you want a perfectly typed key, you'll need to use a `Map`.

Comment: I think having the `x` property be a non-`string` is even more powerful of a demonstration, like `{"3": "ok", "ko": 3}`